# Pourquoi utilise-t-on « si » dans la traduction : « Si on sortait ensemble ce soir ? » ?

Tags: sens, traduction, questions, constructions

Je suis en train d'étudier le français avec Babbel et je dois traduire cette phrase:

> Are we going out tonight?

Et la solution est:

> Si on sortait ensemble ce soir ?

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi la traduction utilise *si*. Je traduirais la phrase comme ceci: « On sortait ensemble ce soir ? ».
Pourquoi « si » est-il utilisé ? Mon alternative est-elle correcte ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Si* + imparfait est équivalent à "how about if...?"

Ton alternative ne marche pas en tant que proposition ; elle veut dire "We were going out tonight?" tout simplement.

Comment: *What if* we went out tonight? French just drops the "*what*".

Answer (score 4):

If the question was phrased “How about we go out tonight?”, the closest French translation would be the suggested:

> Si on sortait (ensemble) ce soir ?

In this case a suggestion is made by introducing a hypothetical situation with “si”.

“Are we going out tonight?” can have a very similar meaning and be translated as above. It is also possible to implicitely make a suggestion like this :

> On sort ce soir ?
>   Est-ce qu'on sort ce soir ?

But these two sentences, like in English, could also be used to ask “Is it the case that we are going out tonight?” (with possibly some stress on *tonight*). They would however be spoken with a different intonation. In writting it's not possible to make a distinction.

Comment: *On sort ce soir ?* : that is spoken French. *Est-ce qu'on sort ce soir ?* is correct. Otherwise you should write: *sort-on ce soir?*

Comment: @Begueradj: You are introducing a mixture of language registers that clearly don't match the language register of the original sentence. This question is not about how to write formal French.

Comment: @Begueradj: actually all of your options are colloquial, the correct phrase would be `sortons-nous ce soir?`  Yet correct usage is fast disappearing.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the solution they provided may not be the best (but it is correct).

Personally, the straight solution would be:

> Allons-nous sortir ce soir ?

Or (the same):

> Va-t-on sortir ce soir ?

Note that you must not confuse the  `Si + imparfait (imperfect)` mentioned above  with the *[si condtionnel](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-71417.php)* where the consequence of the *si* clause [seems impossible, unsure/unlikely](https://www.laits.utexas.edu/tex/pdf/tac3.pdf).

Comment: I would never use *aller* in this context. “Est-ce qu'on sort ce soir” is possible, but not “Va-t-on” or “Allons-nous”.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez *I  would never use aller in this contex* what you stated is completely wrong. This is my last comment.

Comment: Could it be a regional difference maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Il y a une erreur dans la traduction: en aucun cas (quel que soit le contexte) peut-on extraire « Si on sortait ensemble ce soir ? » de « Are we going out tonight? ».

La question (« Are we going out tonight? ») n'est pas une proposition de sortir ensemble; « Si on sortait ensemble ce soir ? » est une proposition, laquelle peut avoir diverses formes en traduction, par exemple:

- What about going out together tonight?
- How about going out together tonight?
- What if we went out together tonight?
- Would you go out with me tonight?
- Should we go out together tonight?
- Shall we go out together tonight? (rather formal)

(« How about we go out tonight? » se trouve depuis environ 1975, mais c'est du très mauvais anglais.)

« Are we going out tonight? » est une vérification dans un ordre normal des choses; la vérification porte sur de possibles prévisions pour une sortie ou de possibles contre-indications. On le traduit donc de la façon la plus simple comme suit:

« Est-ce que l'on sort ce soir? » (un peu formel), « Sortons-nous ce soir? » (formel)

ou  « On sort ce soir? » (informel)

Si on utilisait les variantes suivantes,

« Allons-nous sortir ce soir? »  ou « Va-t-on sortir ce soir? » (assez formel) « On va sortir ce soir? » (informel)

qui sont proches de la possibilité fournie précédemment, on introduirait une nuance, le locuteur parlerais alors selon une prise de conscience commune aux interlocuteurs et antérieure à la formulation de la question; toutes sortes de possibilités sont ouvertes en fait de situation antérieure de cette sorte, par exemple:

- Il pleut tous les jours et la sortie consiste à passer la soirée dans un bal à ciel ouvert.
- D'habitude les interlocuteurs sortent ensemble le soir mais pendant les jours qui ont précédé il ont dû passer leur soirée à travailler en raison de retard qu'il ne sont pas encore sûr d'avoir rattrapé.
- etc.